# How to run the jar located on remote server

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jar

I've managed to build my source from git and put it into S3. Now, I want to run this jar in the post-build phase. The jar is located on S3 as well inside a public bucket, having a read-permission by all.  I've began with a simple `hello-world.jar`, but when I add this to to the code-build's configuration:

```
post_build:
commands:
   - java -jar https://s3.amazonaws.com/*****/hello-world-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I'm getting following error message in the post build phase:

```
Error while executing command: java -jar https://s3.amazonaws.com/*******/hello-world-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. Reason: exit status 1
```

What did I missed?  Is it possible to run a jar which is located at remote server ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of the jar-related API mentioned in **[documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/apiindex.html)**

```
java JarRunner url [arguments]
```

So,

```
java JarRunner https://s3.amazonaws.com/*****/hello-world-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Assuming your jar has `Main-Class` defined in manifest file.

Comment: thanks.  i've added `Main-Class` definition in the pom file, i'm now able to run it locally using `java -jar hello-world-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`, but when i upload it and use `java JarRunner url` i get `Error: Could not find or load main class JarRunner`

Comment: i overcame my problem by using in the pre-build phase a `curl` command with which i copy my remote jar file, and in the post-build phase i simply use `java -jar my.jar`

Comment: @eRez `java -jar my.jar` one of the obvious answer, since your question was very specific to `url` and haven't mentioned anything if you are fine with any alternatives.

Comment: @eRez Also, `Could not find or load main class JarRunner` only possible, you haven't follow exact syntax for `main` method.